# TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'override_encoding'

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, weasyprint

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from weasyprint import HTML
>>> HTML('http://weasyprint.org/').write_pdf('/tmp/weasyprint-website.pdf')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 94, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False)
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'override_encoding'
>>>
```

I believe I have installed all the dependencies. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the same problem as this https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/353.

It might be because you have a out of date `html5lib`. It needs to be at least `html5lib-1.0b9`. If you install `html5lib` though `pip` it may still be `html5lib-1.0b8`. I suggest you update by doing this:

```
pip install --pre html5lib
```

Answer (score -1):

Open file : `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py`

Change this code :

```
result = html5lib.parse(
                    source, treebuilder='lxml', override_encoding=encoding,
                    transport_encoding=protocol_encoding,
                    namespaceHTMLElements=False)
```

To this :

```
result = html5lib.parse(
                    source, treebuilder='lxml'
                )
```

It works for me on `OS` `X` `El` Capitan `10.11.6` (`15G31`)

Comment: Manually editing scripts in installed packages is rarely advisable

Comment: Yes, you're right @JMAA , but sometimes it is your only solution how to solve the problem.